# Next Version of Visual Studi 2015 (Vs2016/Vs2017?)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What is the Next Version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2015?
Is it Visual Studio 2016 or Visual Studio 2017?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3